# Quarkus Opentelemetry - Automatic versus manual context propagation

Tags: java, quarkus, open-telemetry, jaeger, telemetry

I am using Quarkus 2.13.x and trying to get tracing work across multiple services. For individual services tracing works fine. The issue is with tracing requests across multiple services. The demo sample worked fine with automatic context propagation with no extra changes.
However, when i try it in our app, the automatic propagation doesn't work. whereas the manual propagation works when explicitly done with

```
openTelemetry
  .getPropagators()
  .getTextMapPropagator()
  .inject(Context.current(), transportLayer, setter);
```

For the automatic propagation, i am importing the gradle extension

```
io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-extension-trace-propagators
```

and also set the propagators in the `application.properties` to

```
quarkus.opentelemetry.propagators=tracecontext,baggage,jaeger
```

However the manual approach works and the automated one doesn't.

Do i need to do anything else for the automatic propagation to work? Also we are using Jaeger collector for the traces

Comment: Turns out this was working in the demo application because it was using org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.RestClientBuilder. When i switched to it, i started seeing traceids getting propagated.  Also i noticed the trace id is not getting logged at all though the context has the trace and span ids. has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: It should work out of the box, by just including the Quarkus OpenTelemetry Extension. Any chance you can provide us with a copy of your code so we can have a look? You can also open an issue in Quarkus: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues